# using .where with .class.superclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to figure out a way to retrieve a group of instances from the database using `.where`.

Is it possible to use `.where` based on the `class.superclass`?
For example, i would like to do something like `Person.where(class.superclass: "Adult")`.

But i'm not sure on the syntax, or if this is even possible. I can't find much about this approach on google.
Thanks.

Comment: Which columns does `Person` model have?

Comment: Do you have STI on that table?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is your inheritance structure? Having an inheritance relationship between `Person` and `Adult` seems, well, curious. But, I'm sure you have your reasons...